# show a message on timeout, for only two seconds

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout, promise

I have the following code that shows a message if a promise doesn't return after five seconds:

```
$timeout(function () {
        if (!$scope.promiseComplete && $scope.submitted) {
          $scope.message = {
            content: [{
              title: '',
              msg: 'Service down - created'
            }],
            type: 'error'
          };
          return;
        }
      }, 5000)
```

My dilemma is that I would only like to show this message itself for two seconds. I tried the following and it worked, is it an anti pattern to "nest" timeouts?

```
$timeout(function () {
        if (!$scope.promiseComplete && $scope.submitted) {
          $scope.message = {
            content: [{
              title: '',
              msg: 'Service down -  Railcar ASN created'
            }],
            type: 'error'
          };
          $timeout(function(){
            $scope.message = null;
          }, 2000)
          return;
        }

      }, 5000)
```

Update: based on answer here is what I went with:

```
 $timeout(function () {
        if (!$scope.promiseComplete && $scope.submitted) {
          $scope.message = {
            content: [{
              title: '',
              msg: 'Service down -  created'
            }],
            type: 'error'
          };
          return $timeout(function(){
            $scope.message = null;
          }, 2000)
        }
      }, 5000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$timeout` is promise-based, it returns a promise that can be chained. Yes, nested `$timeout`s or any other promises [may be an antipattern](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/#nested-promises:8f173b15e2d19515fdc8ce931ae539c0).

This kind of promise chain

```
  $timeout(function () {
    if (!$scope.promiseComplete && $scope.submitted) {
      ...
      return $timeout(function(){
        $scope.message = null;
      }, 2000)
    }
  }, 5000)
```

guarantees that there would be no more than 2 levels of nesting, and the promise returned by top `$timeout` can be utilized, the whole promise chain may be extended or tested.

Comment: I'm editing my post with the updated answer...is that what it should look like? I'm also confused, how is it that the outer timeout will run first, then the inner one?

Comment: Yes, it would look like that. The order of execution is the same as with `setTimeout`. Timeout callback function is fired once the delay time has passed, not a millisecond earlier.

Comment: I see. Wouldn't it be better to chain a .then on the outer timeout, containing the inner timeout?

Comment: Not really. Excessive `then` is an [another antipattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-thensuccess-fail-anti-pattern). `then` appears only when third promise shows up in the chain: `$timeout(() => { return $timeout(() => { ... }, 2000) }, 5000).then(() => $timeout(() => { ... }, 1000))`